# While statement loop error

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, repeat, mpeg

Hey I have been having an issue with this code because it has not been looping when I input a value for the String repeat.  I am unable to understand whatever it is that I'm doing wrong.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MpgCalculator
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to the MPG and CPM Calculator!");
        double startOd, endOd, gallons, cost, mpg, cpm;
        String repeat = "yes";
        while(repeat.equals("yes")||repeat.equals("Yes")||repeat.equals("y")||repeat.equals("Y"))
        {
            System.out.println("Please Enter:");
            System.out.print("\tYour Starting Odometer Reading: ");
            startOd = sc.nextDouble();
            System.out.print("\tYour Ending Odometer Reading: ");
            endOd = sc.nextDouble();
            System.out.print("\tThe Amount of Gallons Used: ");
            gallons = sc.nextDouble();
            System.out.print("\tThe Cost-per-Gallon That You Spent: ");
            cost = sc.nextDouble();
            mpg = getMpg(startOd, endOd, gallons);
            cpm = getCpm(mpg, cost);
            System.out.println("\nYour Miles-per-Gallon is " + mpg + ".");
            System.out.println("Your Cost-per-Mile is " + cpm + ".");
            System.out.print("Do it again? ");
            repeat = sc.nextLine();
        }
    }
    public static double getMpg(double startOd, double endOd, double gallons)
    {
        double mpg;
        mpg = (endOd - startOd) / gallons;
        return mpg;
    }
    public static double getCpm(double mpg, double cost)
    {
        double cpm;
        cpm = cost / mpg;
        return cpm;
    }
}
```

Comment: Put a break point on your while statement and see what he value of 'repeat' is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `repeat = sc.nextLine();` to `repeat = sc.next();` If you don't need the extra line. It only gets it if you are an the next line, which you are not, so it terminates the program.

Answer (score 0):

The previous use of your `Scanner` prior to calling `repeat = sc.nextLine();` in your `while` loop is `nextDouble`.  Calling `nextDouble` does not consume the newline character in the stream from entering the cost per gallon.

Consume the newline character before asking to repeat:

```
System.out.print("Do it again? ");
String dummy = sc.nextLine();  // Add this line.
repeat = sc.nextLine();
```

Comment: I'd probably just have moved away from `nextLine` altogether and used `next` instead. Oh, and what's the point of `String dummy =`? You don't **need** to use the return value.

Comment: @Dukeling Just to emphasize that it's a throwaway value.

Comment: I had tried a throwaway value and when I test ran it and compiled it, it caused an exception error and crashed.  Just replacing sc.nextLine with sc.next seems to be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

use 
repeat = sc.next();
instead of 
repeat = sc.nextLine();